# AbstractValidator : showing error messages with property values

Tags: fluentvalidation

I use the following pattern when importing "unknown" data.

```
public class MyCustomObject
{
    public string MyCustomDateAsString { get; set; }

    public DateTime? MyCustomDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime? returnValue = null;
            DateTime parseResult = DateTime.MinValue;
            bool parseAttempt = DateTime.TryParse(this.MyCustomDateAsString, out parseResult);
            if (parseAttempt)
            {
                returnValue = parseResult;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    public string MyCustomIntAsString { get; set; }


    public int? MyCustomInt
    {
        get
        {
            int? returnValue = null;
            int parseResult = 0;
            bool parseAttempt = int.TryParse(this.MyCustomIntAsString, out parseResult);
            if (parseAttempt)
            {
                returnValue = parseResult;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }   

}
```

I have this working.

```
public class MyCustomObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<MyCustomObject>
{
    public MyCustomObjectValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(custobj => custobj.MyCustomDateAsString).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a MyCustomDateAsString");
        RuleFor(custobj => custobj.MyCustomIntAsString).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a MyCustomIntAsString");

    }
}
```

I want to add these rules.

```
        RuleFor(custobj => custobj.MyCustomDate).NotNull().WithMessage("MyCustomDate must be a valid non null date.  You specified '{0}'"); /* How can I put MyCustomDateAsString for the {0} */
        RuleFor(custobj => custobj.MyCustomInt).NotNull().WithMessage("MyCustomInt must be a valid non null int.  You specified '{0}'"); /* How can I put MyCustomIntAsString for the {0} */
```

But I don't know how to get the MyCustomDateAsString and MyCustomIntAsString to show up in the error messages for MyCustomDate and MyCustomInt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with most validators you'd use the {PropertyValue} placeholder to get the current property value but this doesn't help in this case as you want the value of a different property.

However, There's an overload of WithMessage that takes a func that you can use to build custom placehold values.

```
RuleFor(x=>x.Foo).NotNull().WithMessage("...blah {0}", x=>x.SomeOtherProperty);
```

The final argument is actually a params array of Func[T,object] so you can specify as many of these as you like, and they're processed in order.